# LTspice unicode trouble with micro symbol

Tags: ltspice

I am having a pretty simple issue with LTspice, I built my circuit and it works fine, but the units for the capacitors don't display properly and I get the that "fE" unicode error I guess instead of the proper symbol for micro, I tried to find a setting to make it stop using any symbol and just display u or something alike. I want to show the circuit neatly on a presentation and having the proper units either as u or micro symbol would help a lot. Currently the best bet I have is just hiding that text.

The images I provide are a segment of my schematic and the settings for the capacitor, I actually have to type 5u in the box and when I apply the settings it changes automatically to that micro symbol. it displays properly there but not on the schematic.

[image: Schematic Display]

[image: Settings display]

Comment: It looks like the character encoding is not set up properly.   The renderer is not set to UTF-8.

Comment: do you know of any place where I can change that option. Honestly, I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with LTSpice.  But I am familiar with charset encodings: it looks very much like the µ sign has been entered in UTF-8 but rendered in ISO8859-1 (or a common derivative).

Comment: What LTSpice, IV or XVII? I suspect the latter one is more likely to have unicode working. Also note there are *two* things that look like a micro, the 'micro sign' at 00B5, and the greek alphabet micro character at 03BC, there might be a difference with LTSpice.

Comment: You have a few font without support. Set it to another with support for these characters

Comment: By any chance, was this schematic downloaded? Sometimes, websites do not properly interpret Unicode characters and mess the whole file (since `.asc` files are ASCII, or Unicode) and, when opening them up, they show up as in your example, despite your OS having correct character setup. The solution, in this case, would be to simply rename those characters with `u`, and LTspice will take care of the rest. If there are many instances, a search-replace with your favourite text editor should do. If what I say is not the case for you, then please ignore my comment.

Comment: it was not downloaded, built it myself, the thing is I do try to rename the characters with u, LTspice itself will swap the u for the micro character and I end up with that. I never input the micro symbol at any point it is all LTspice.

Comment: Are you manually inserting the \$\mu\$ symbol, or are you letting LTspice do the conversion, by itself? If you are troubled so much by it, you can change the automatic conversion in `Settings > Netlist options > Convert '`\$\mu\$`' to 'u'`